# how to filter out empty string in odata $filter

Tags: odata

In odata v4, my query

```
_odata/Order?$filter=Country ne ''
```

returns empty array whereas if i do

```
_odata/Order?$filter=length(Country) gt 0
```

It returns all orders with non empty string country.
Am i using empty string filter correctly?

Comment: I checked both variations on our odata v4 service and get identical results (i.e. the desired result). Therefore I assume you are using the filter coreectly. Pls. check again if there is really a problem and add more details if the problem persists.